# 'how to layout convert into square image in android

Tags: android

I tried to convert the layout to a square image successfully, but the square image I found is too bad.

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap? {
    val bitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)
    val newBitmap = BITMAP_RESIZER(bitmap, 1080, 1080)
    return newBitmap
}

fun bitmapResizer(bitmap: Bitmap, newWidth: Int, newHeight: Int): Bitmap? {
    val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val ratioX = newWidth / bitmap.width.toFloat()
    val ratioY = newHeight / bitmap.height.toFloat()
    val middleX = newWidth / 2.0f
    val middleY = newHeight / 2.0f
    val scaleMatrix = Matrix()
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY)
    val canvas = Canvas(scaledBitmap)
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix)
    canvas.drawBitmap(
        bitmap,
        middleX - bitmap.width / 2,
        middleY - bitmap.height / 2,
        Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG)
    )
    return scaledBitmap
}
```

[here is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeINO.png)

[here I found square image but not perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqs5b.png)

I want to convert layout to image into square.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would suggest that you first change the box to a square, before capturing the layout into an image. That way, the rest of the stuff won't be distorted like that, and you don't have to worry about resizing the image after capture.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. it is possible without changing the box to square?

Comment: Do you have access to the box layout in order to change it to square? That would be the easiest.

Comment: If you have an example. So give me, then I try.